# I have installed winfonts package as well as the microsoft true type fonts. Pdflatex is unablet find arial.ttf

Tags: pdftex, truetype

I am using texlive on Ubuntu 17.10. I have installed winfonts package. I have also installed microsoft fonts. However, pdflatex is unable to find arial.ttf. I get the following error message:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/local/bin/pdflatex (file arial.ttf): cannot open 
TrueType font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: You have to use XeLaTeX and not LaTeX to be able to use your system fonts. See here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525779/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-latex. This is the suggested solution for useing any font of your system without need of specific latex packages etc. If you used a code that should work with pdflatex, then may be the font file has not the appropriate permissions. You have to browse to the font file's folder and give the command `chmod 754 arial.ttf`...

Comment: Where is Arial.ttf? Did you put it in the texmf in fonts/teletype? Did you run mktexlsr?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. I created a symbolic link to the directory containing arial.ttf under /texmf-dist/fonts/truetype and ran texhash. Pdflatex works fine now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I created a symbolic link to the directory containing arial.ttf under /texmf-dist/fonts/truetype and ran texhash. It worked.